# $\mu=0$ for CM Elliptic curves?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, iwasawa-theory, complex-multiplication

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $F$ with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field. We may assume the $F$ contains $K$ and also contains the $p$-division points, where $p$ is a good ordinary prime. When $K$ has class number 1, Schnepps' (and Gillard’s) results tell us that the $\mu$-invariant of the dual Selmer over the division field extension (the split prime) is zero. Is it reasonable to believe that the $\mu$-invariant for the dual Selmer over the cyclotomic extension is zero as well for a CM elliptic curve?

Comment: This question has been addressed by Burungale and Hida for anticyclotomic extensions in "p-rigidity and Iwasawa $\mu$-invariants" I don't think it has been studied for the cyclotomic extension.

Comment: Just noted this questoin. I think it is a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59294/iwasawa-mu-invariant-for-abelian-extensions-of-quadratic-number-fields